# Spawn a background process in Ruby on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, fork, background-process

I am basically asking the same question as [Spawn a background process in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504445/spawn-a-background-process-in-ruby), except I need to spawn a background process in a Windows environment!  Unfortunately, my research has revealed that Windows doesn't support Ruby forks (only spoons. *Rimshot!*).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The win32-process library, part of the Win32Utils suite, is probably what you're after.

http://win32utils.rubyforge.org/

> The win32-process library adds the Process.create and Process.fork methods for MS Windows. In add addition, it provides different implementations of the wait, wait2, waitpid, and waitpid2 methods.
>   The Process.create method allows you to create native MS Windows processes using a variety of different configuration options.
>
> The Process.fork implementation should be considered experimental and not used in production code.
>
> Installation: gem install win32-process

Comment: `Process.fork` has been removed from win32-process since 0.7.0 (see [github page](https://github.com/djberg96/win32-process)), you can use `Process.spawn` as @rogerdpack suggests

Answer (score 6):

Charles's answer is great. I also discovered that I can utilize Windows's `start`, for example to execute the `dir` command as such:

```
system('start dir')
```

This spawns a cmd window along with the process, which is undesirable in some circumstances.  However, if this is tolerable, then you don't need the win32-process dependency :)

Comment: @stack1 My code sample now contains an actual command, `dir`. Whichever command you use is arbitrary, so long as it can be resolved by the command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

1.9.x's Process.spawn seems to work well, see the last section of http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Running_Multiple_Processes