# Start foreman from a Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, shell, foreman

I just created a script/run in my project in the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# set some ENV variables..
`foreman start -f Procfile.dev`
```

So, I have some questions:

1. If I set a `ENV["EMAIL_USERNAME"]` from the ruby script, will rails be able to read it?
2. Running foreman in that way seems like doens't work. It just stuck. Is there another way?

Yeah, I do know that I cant export a ENV variable to PATH, but I wish I can made the variable be exported to the app only.

PS: It could be in bash too.

Comment: See this question: [Spawn a background process in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2504445/7552)

Comment: it solves everything! thank you very much. Now, how can I give you your points for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I made it work following glenn jackman's link: [Spawn a background process in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2504445/7552)

Just call exec instead of put the command between `

Thanks.