# Setting Connection to "close" in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, http, sinatra

I have this simple sinatra web app:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    "Success."
end

get '/app' do
    "done"
    response["Connection"] = "Close"
    `sudo pkill blink` 
    `gpio write 0 0` 
    `sudo ./blink #{params["func"]}`
end
```

`./blink` is a program that runs forever and does not terminate, so when I access `http://127.0.0.1/app?func=2` in a browser, I just get a loading loop and `"done"` is not shown as the result, however the program I am trying to run in the `/app` block is running.

I thought maybe setting the `Connection` header to `Close` would solve the problem, but using the code above, which I thought would set the header, still has the `Connection` header to `Keep-Alive`

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: It seems "done" shoud be placed at the end of the `do ... end` block after all other stuff, so the block should return this value. HTTP header `Connection=close` is far enough from what you need.

Comment: @andrykonchin I tried that and it doesn't show "done" until after I shut down the server, which shuts down the `./blink` as well, so I still get the long loading loop

Comment: .Are you sure  all your shell commands are completed fast and don't delay the response? Can you add some sort of logging to see all lines are executed or some lne are't execited?

Comment: @andrykonchin Like I said, the `sudo ./blink #{params["func"]}` line is executing a forever running program that does not complete/return

Comment: oh, sure, I got it. Have you tried to detach from the shell process with `&` command like `sudo ./blink #{params["func"]} &`?

Comment: @andrykonchin Just did, no such luck :(

Comment: Hm, can you check in terminal this command? Your shell comand have to   release you terminal at least. Is it true (it releases) the issue is in another place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97093/discussion-between-vikaton-and-andrykonchin).

Answer (score 1):

Referencing this SO question [Spawn a background process in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504445/spawn-a-background-process-in-ruby) and with some help from @andrykonchin, I was able to resolve my issue using this:

```
pid = fork do
        `sudo ./blink #{params["func"]}`
    end
Process.detach(pid)
```

Comment: I'd add that unless you want to spawn a new process every time that route is hit, you should consider writing a file (or something) that indicates the process is already running, or allows you to check, and then change the route verb from a GET to a PUT or POST to indicate idempotence.